# scala sbt-launch.jar - multiple projects ihe same directory?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm sure this is simple, but I haven't figured it out yet...

I've installed `sbt-launch.jar` and a shell script to execute it (named `sbt`).

How do I put multiple projects in the same directory?

When I run `sbt` the directories `project` and `target` get created and populated, and the current project is `default-XXXXX`. The `compile` command picks up source files in the top-level directory and jar files in the top-level 'lib' directory.

How do I add another project under the same directory? Every time I run `sbt` in an empty directory it creates a 20+ MB `project` directory.

Note 1: when I run `sbt` I an *not* getting asked "Create new project?" or any other questions.

Note 2: I am using sbt-launch.jar from this url: http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/0.10.1/sbt-launch.jar

and I'm following the instructions at: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer (for sbt 0.10.1):

Create the file `project/Build.scala` that looks like this:

```
import sbt._
object MyBuild extends Build
{

  lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
  lazy val sub1: Project = Project("proj1", file("dir1"));
  lazy val sub2 = Project("proj2", file("dir2"))
}
```

This creates three projects 'root' (in the top-level directory), 'proj1' (in the sub-directory 'dir1') and 'proj2' (in the sub-directory 'dir2')

For more info, see https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration

Comment: Note that this is only for SBT 0.10.x, not 0.7.x (as suggested by the URL of the SBT binary). The same thing is possible in SBT 0.7 with a different syntax.